# What are the current books for DirectX (w/ focus on 3D)?

Tags: c++, directx

For OpenGL, the OpenGL SuperBible 5th edition was just released only a few months ago, and is considered a fantastic, highly rated book for not only learning OpenGL 3 (Part 1 of the book), but it also goes into advanced OpenGL topics in Parts 2 and 3.

For DirectX, what is the current material we should be reading to learn? Books & websites with tutorials welcome. Are there any modern books available that go through the CURRENT version of DirectX that are intended for a beginning audience with a decent grasp of C++, but with no experience for DirectX at all?

This one seems to be highly praised : [Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0028085RK)

Comment: See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2014/04/07/book-recommendations.aspx).

Comment: https://walbourn.github.io/book-recommendations/

Answer (score 18):

Unlike OpenGL, which has a hodgepodge of tutorials, many vendors and implementations, and good but somewhat archaic (unless you're like me and enjoy reading man page style) reference documentation, DirectX has one implementation, and [Microsoft maintains a good DirectX hub on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/default.aspx).

Not that there aren't good books about DirectX, but [many of these tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416804%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) are equivalent in content and more up-to-date, e.g. [the DirectX 11 tutorial and samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416568%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Wow that 2nd to last link you gave me was incredible. The DirectX tutorials right from the MSDN seem to be concise and filled with only the information needed to progress to the next step of DirectX. Fantastic, thanks! [I can't vote you up yet, but will when I get 15 reputation :)]

Answer (score 13):

Frank Luna's books on DX9 and DX10 are really the only good books on Direct3D that I've seen. His DX11 book isn't due out until next year I think (it seems he had to find another publisher), but DX11 is close enough to DX10 as far as basic 3d graphics goes.

The only thing I'll say is that the title is a little bit misleading because there's no actual game programming in there - it is purely a graphics programming book.

UPDATE: It's worth noting that [Frank Luna's DirectX 11 book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1942270062) is out now.

Just an update to this answer. Frank Luna's book are very good for learning DirectX where one doesn't need to cram the syntax and get the mathematical detail of everything what's going on.

Frank Luna's [DirectX 12 book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1942270062)

Comment: I have the DX9 version of the book and enjoyed it. I wonder if I should look into buying the DX11 version though, my DX knowledge is extremely outdated already...

Comment: The main problem is that Frank Luna's DX11 book focuses on developing using the legacy DirectX SDK so all the content about D3DX11 is outdated. The XNAMath material is 'outdated' but easily applies to DirectXMath. He also makes heavy use of Effects 11 which is fine and works, but the compiler support for it is deprecated. All of these issues are easily adjusted for (see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/08/21/living-without-d3dx.aspx), so the book is still very useful.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a solid and up to date textbook then I highly recommend [Practice Rendering and Computation with Direct3D11](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568817207). The book thoroughly covers all of the DirectX11 resources, the entire rendering pipeline, tessellation, DirectCompute, HLSL, multithreaded rendering, and then thorough discussions on common implementations of mesh rendering, dynamic tessellation, image processing, deferred rendering, simulations (using DirectCompute), and multithreaded paraboloid mapping.

It's a lot of information. Took me about half a year to work through. However, it doesn't leave my desk now while I'm working on my game.

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure, if you do pick up a book, that it includes some chapters on the HLSL topic, as there is no more fixex pipeline in DX10+. Many books seem to not cover that subject at all, which is a big mistake IMO.
The msdn is a great HLSL resource.