# What do you need to know in C++ before starting to program with DirectX

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, graphics-programming

I was wondering what do you need to know in C++ before starting to program with DirectX?

I have only been programming in C++ (more for 2D games using SDL and learning the basics) for just over a year, I was wondering what kind of concepts and methods should someone be knowledgeable with or at least have seen before, before attempting to learn how to use Direct X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Direct3D itself does not require you to know C++.
You'll need to understand function pointers and structure layouts from C.

However, to design a good architecture for even a simple game, you'll better be good in C++.

Comment: Hey. Agreed - also, note that C++ is noted for being a language which is bloated with features, which interact in irksome ways. There is an argument to be made that sometimes it is better to use a simple and well-understood subset of C++ that isn't too far off plain old C, in order to produce programs that are more maintainable.

Comment: @Tartley, I mostly agree. For example take a look at the Alexandrescu's Loki library for many examples on "how to code C++ so that no one else will ever understand". However, there are also C++ concepts that improve code quality compared to the C, when used properly. Data encapsulation, pure virtual interfaces, RIIA resource management classes, and ATL/STL template containers, to name a few.

Comment: Yeah, good call Soonts. Very fair.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416804(v=VS.85).aspx

I'm assuming if you can follow the tutorials then you know enough.

Link blatantly stolen from an answer in this question: [What are the current books for DirectX (w/ focus on 3D)?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5490/what-are-the-current-books-for-directx-w-focus-on-3d)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, but not 100% the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any C++ for DirectX programming, so just use however much or little C++ you're comfortable with.