# How did you learn DirectX 11?

Tags: books, directx11

How did you learn the DirectX 11 API? MSDN documentation, tutorials, blogs, sample applications, books, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the current books for DirectX (w/ focus on 3D)?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5490/what-are-the-current-books-for-directx-w-focus-on-3d)

Comment: Well, I specifically and only want D3D11 information and would like to know how the people that currently (and hopefully professionally) use it, learned it. Sigh, I feel like I get more question critiques than answers on this site. Which is understandable but extremely frustrating.

Comment: Well, the question says "Are there any modern books available that go through the CURRENT version of DirectX" and the current version of DX at the time of that question was still 11 (and had been for over a year).

Comment: You are right, however I feel it's lacking. I don't see any discussion as to how successful someone has been with any of these resources. (MSDN is driving me nuts) I suppose I need to word my question better then.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the documentation & samples comes with DirectX itself?

yeh, its true that MSDN is perfectly capable driving someone crazy. :)

Here is one I like:

http://www.rastertek.com/tutindex.html

there is a book that *will be* released on July 18 this year,

[Practical Rendering and Computation with Direct3D 11](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568817207)

(Does ask which way to go, I'm no DirectX guy)

Comment: I am curious to know why the down vote?

Comment: Thanks though! My only problem with the rastertek tutorials is it's a pain in the ass to navigate through his code architecture on that site and I believe I've seen discrepancies between it and MSDN. Now the Practical Rendering book looks very promising and it sounds like what I want at least until Luna releases a new book.

Comment: Annnd it looks like it hasn't been released. :(

Comment: @joel :P fixed.

Comment: The question is "How did you learn DirectX 11?", your answer is a book that you _didn't read and doesn't exist yet_, and you're wondering why it got downvoted?

Comment: @joe-wreschnig If you take Joel's second line into your account, it is clear that the whole question is "How do *I* learn DirectX?". And for the book, there is only [another](http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-DirectX-11-Game-Programming/dp/1435458958/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1310392820&sr=1-1) exists on DX11, which i know, isn't good. That's why the new one. And please comment while down voting so its clear to everybody.

Comment: I apologize, I derailed this question by being vague and just taking the first answer I got. I'm still getting into the swing of things here! @iamcreasy Is MSDN and Rastertek how you learned the API?

Comment: @joel I started with Rastertek but switched to OpenGL later.